# Magento - strange characters in invoice PDF

Tags: magento, pdf

Getting a strange character appearing at the end of each custom option in a PDF invoice. See the image below. Any ideas what this character might be?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the case that the current PDF's font library that is used, doesn't support certain characters.
By default it uses the following Font library for PDF Generation: LinLibertineC_Re-2.8.0.ttf

In order to change the default PDF Font:

1. Get the desired font library's TTF-file and place it in the lib folder of your Magento installation.
2. Edit the following files (better mirror it instead of editing core files directly) in order to switch the font:

   - /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php
   - /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php

Comment: How do I change the font that is being used?

Comment: Hello, get the desired TTF-file you would like to use. Edit the following files: /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php and /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Abstract.php

Comment: Appreciate the update, I'll give this a go and see if it has resolved the issue.